# Getting Abstract error in method in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I am getting error: sound method can't be abstract. But, when I remove 'abstract', I get class Dog and Cat needs to be abstract. What am I doing wrong?

The task says that class Dog and Cat should remain concrete. Task is below.

```
package inheritance

abstract class Animal(name: String) {
  abstract def sound(): String

  override def toString(): Animal
}

class Cat(var name: String)
  extends Animal(name) {
  override def sound() = {
    "meow"
  }
}

class Dog(var name: String)
  extends Animal(name) {
  override def sound() = {
    "woof"
  }
}

object Park {
  def animals() = {
    List(new Dog("Snoopy"), new Dog("Finn"), new Cat("Garfield"), new
        Cat("Morris"))
  }

  def makeSomeNoise(first: List[Animal]): List[String] = first.map(_.sound())
}
```

Task:

Question: [Scala] In a package named "inheritance" create an abstract class named "Animal" and concrete classes named "Cat" and "Dog".

Create an object named "Park":

Animal: A constructor that takes a String called name
(Do not use either val or var. It will be declared in the base classes);

An abstract method named sound that takes no parameters and returns a String

• Override toString to return the name of this Animal

Cat: Inherent Animal;
A constructor that take a String called name as a value (use val to declare name); Override sound() to return "meow

"Dog: Inherent Animal; A constructor that take a String called name as a value (use val to declare name); Override sound() to return "woof"

Park:
• A method named "animals" that take no parameters and returns a list of animals containing

• 2 dogs with names "Snoopy" and "Finn"

• 2 cats with names "Garfield" and"Morris"

• A method named "makeSomeNoise" that takes a list of animals as a parameter and returns a list of strings containing the noises from each animal in the input list

Comment: Please don't change your question, after the fact, such that the submitted answer(s) no longer have sufficient context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's tackle a few of these.

> An abstract method named sound that takes no parameters and returns a String

The modifier `abstract` is only used on class definitions. An abstract method is a method within an abstract class, and that method has no body, only the name and types are presented.

> Override toString to return the name of this Animal

You haven't done this. Currently your `toString` method is also abstract.

> Cat: Inherent Animal; A constructor that take a String called name as a value (use val to declare name); Override sound() to return "meow"

It says here to use `val` but your code has `var`.

So the reason you're having problems with `Cat` and `Dog` is because `Animal`, as you currently define it, has two abstract methods and you need to implement (override) both to create an instance of the animal.

Fix the `toString` method so that it is no longer abstract, and returns the correct result, and you should be good to go.

Comment: How would I fix toString method? It is not 'override def toString(): Animal'

Comment: The instructions say to return the `name` of the animal. As it is, your method doesn't return anything, but it is defined to return an instance of type `Animal`, which is not what's required.

Comment: 'override def toString(): {name}' Like this?

Comment: Don't forget the equals `=` sign. (Use `override def sound()` as a template.)

Comment: I did this 'override def toString() : Any = {name}' and got incompatible type

Comment: Why did you define it to return `Any` when that's not what it returns?

Comment: What type does `toString()` usually return when it isn't overridden? What is the type of the variable `name`?

Comment: toString() returns type string

Comment: Then you have your answer. And it is `String` (capitol S), not string.